# Cosecant graph with \pi coordinates

Tags: beamer, plot

How to draw a cosecant, secant and cotangent graphs with coordinates in terms of \pi in LaTeX `beamer`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What have you tried so far? Please add a minimal working example (MWE) of your current code.

Answer (score 2):

If a TikZ solution is required,

Starting from the example on p 1047 of the TikZ manual (`texdoc pgfmanual`),

[image: example]

a starting point could perhaps be something like this:

[image: graph]

Note that this is only from 15 minutes` worth of trying things out and looking up the manual (it's too cold for further exploration today). Much more sophisticated plots are possible, obviously. But even so, the inherent inter-relationships between the various functions are already quite apparent.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


%=====================================
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (3,2);
\draw [blue, thick, x=0.0085cm, y=1cm,
declare function={
sines(\t,\a,\b)=1 + 0.5*(sin(\t)+sin(\t*\a)+sin(\t*\b));
}]
plot [domain=0:360, samples=144, smooth] (\x,{sines(\x,3,5)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (0,-2) grid (3,2);
\draw [blue, thick, x=0.0085cm, y=1cm] plot [domain=0:360, samples=144, smooth] (\x,{sin(\x)}) node[above] {$sin$};
\draw [red, thick, x=0.0085cm, y=1cm] plot [domain=0:360, samples=144, smooth] (\x,{cos(\x)}) node[above] {$cos$};
\draw [green, thick, x=0.0085cm, y=1cm] plot [domain=0:70, samples=144, smooth] (\x,{tan(\x)}) node[above] {$tan$};
\draw [brown, dotted, thick, x=0.0085cm, y=1cm] plot [domain=0:70, samples=144, smooth] (\x,{sec(\x)}) node[above] {$sec$};
\draw [blue, dashed, thick, x=0.0085cm, y=1cm] plot [domain=30:150, samples=144, smooth] (\x,{cosec(\x)}) node[above] {$cosec$};
\draw [black, dashed, thin, x=0.0085cm, y=1cm, pin=90:$cot$] plot [domain=15:155, samples=144, smooth] (\x,{cot(\x)}) node[above] {$cot$};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

---

Addendum

Indeed, section 81.5 (p 857) of the manual is exactly on-point, and re-inventing the wheel is not required.

That section of the manual deals with applying styles, and uses the `\datavisualization` command on sin/cos/tan. With that code as template, adding more functions becomes a trivial exercise.

For reference:

```
\usetikzlibrary {datavisualization.formats.functions}
```

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\datavisualization [ scientific axes=clean,
y axis=grid,
visualize as smooth line/.list={sin,cos,tan},
style sheet=strong colors,
style sheet=vary dashing,
sin={label in legend={text=$\sin x$}},
cos={label in legend={text=$\cos x$}},
tan={label in legend={text=$\tan x$}},
data/format=function ]
data [set=sin] {
var x : interval [-0.5*pi:4];
func y = sin(\value x r);
}
data [set=cos] {
var x : interval [-0.5*pi:4];
func y = cos(\value x r);
}
data [set=tan] {
var x : interval [-0.3*pi:.3*pi];
func y = tan(\value x r);
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

Addendum 2:

While we're waiting for the MWE, further perusal of the manual, -- and keeping within the 32k calculation value barrier as a first approximation --, has yielded:

[image: trig]

It's a bit 'busy' to take it all in at once.

A layered presentation, revealing parts at a time, would be a useful didactic method.

And considering the amount of hand-coding needed in and by a typesetting engine to achieve this (mostly to avoid the edges of infinity), it is likely that large-volume, multiple output graph sets of this type would probably be more practically produced by a dedicated graphing app, and then imported into latex.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{red!3}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {datavisualization.formats.functions}


%=====================================
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\datavisualization [ scientific axes=clean,
y axis = {ticks=few,grid},
x axis = {ticks=few,ticks and grid ={ major at={%
    (-2*pi) as $-2\pi$, 
    (-3*pi/2) as $\frac{-3\pi}{2}$, 
    (-pi) as $-\pi$, 
    (-pi/2) as $\frac{-\pi}{2}$, 
    (0) as $0$, 
    (pi/2) as $\frac{\pi}{2}$, 
    (pi) as $\pi$, 
    (3*pi/2) as $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, 
    (2*pi) as $2\pi$, 
    }}},
visualize as smooth line/.list={sin,cos,tan,tan2,tan3,sec,sec2,sec3,cosec,cosec2,cosec3,cosec4,cot,cot2,cot3,cot4},
style sheet=strong colors,
%style sheet=vary dashing,
sin={label in legend={text=$\sin x$}},
cos={label in legend={text=$\cos x$}},
tan={label in legend={text=$\tan x$},style={visualizer color=blue!50, densely dotted, thick}},
tan2={style={visualizer color=blue!50, densely dotted, thick}},
tan3={style={visualizer color=blue!50, densely dotted, thick}},
sec={label in legend={text=$\sec x$},style={visualizer color=brown, dash dot, thick}},
sec2={style={visualizer color=brown, dash dot, thick}},
sec3={style={visualizer color=brown, dash dot, thick}},
cosec={label in legend={text=$\csc x$},style={visualizer color=green!50!black, dash dot dot, thick}},
cosec2={style={visualizer color=green!50!black, dash dot dot, thick}},
cosec3={style={visualizer color=green!50!black, dash dot dot, thick}},
cosec4={style={visualizer color=green!50!black, dash dot dot, thick}},
cot={label in legend={text=$\cot x$},style={visualizer color=red!50, densely dashed, thick}},
cot2={style={visualizer color=red!50, densely dashed, thick}},
cot3={style={visualizer color=red!50, densely dashed, thick}},
cot4={style={visualizer color=red!50, densely dashed, thick}},
data/format=function ]
data [set=sin] {
var x : interval [-2*pi:2*pi];
func y = sin(\value x r);
}
data [set=cos] {
var x : interval [-2*pi:2*pi];
func y = cos(\value x r);
}
data [set=tan] {
var x : interval [-0.3*pi:.35*pi];
func y = tan(\value x r);
}
data [set=tan2] {
var x : interval [(pi/2)+0.45:3*pi/2-0.45];
func y = tan(\value x r);
}
data [set=tan3] {
var x : interval [(-3*pi/2)+0.45:-pi/2-0.45];
func y = tan(\value x r);
}
data [set=sec] {
var x : interval [(-pi/2)+0.45:pi/2-0.45];
func y = sec(\value x r);
}
data [set=sec2] {
var x : interval [(pi/2)+0.45:3*pi/2-0.45];
func y = sec(\value x r);
}
data [set=sec3] {
var x : interval [(-3*pi/2)+0.45:-pi/2-0.45];
func y = sec(\value x r);
}
data [set=cosec] {
var x : interval [(0)+0.45:pi-0.45];
func y = cosec(\value x r);
}
data [set=cosec2] {
var x : interval [(-pi)+0.45:0-0.45];
func y = cosec(\value x r);
}
data [set=cosec3] {
var x : interval [(pi)+0.45:2*pi-0.45];
func y = cosec(\value x r);
}
data [set=cosec4] {
var x : interval [(-2*pi)+0.45:-pi-0.45];
func y = cosec(\value x r);
}
data [set=cot] {
var x : interval [0+0.55:pi-0.55];
func y = cot(\value x r);
}
data [set=cot2] {
var x : interval [(pi)+0.55:2*pi-0.55];
func y = cot(\value x r);
}
data [set=cot3] {
var x : interval [(-pi)+0.55:0-0.55];
func y = cot(\value x r);
}
data [set=cot4] {
var x : interval [(-2*pi)+0.55:-pi-0.55];
func y = cot(\value x r);
}
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: suggest add pi ticks on the axis also

Comment: @jsbibra pi ticks added; see edited answer.